# Create Wireless Access Point Without Ethernet

Tags: wifi, pi-4, access-point, hotspot

Using the built-in WiFi hotspot configuration GUI, I realize that there isn't any way to make this hotspot provide an internet connection without an Ethernet cable or WiFi adapter. I'm in a really specific scenario where I don't have access to either of these, is there any way to still set a hotspot up without more than the basics? By "basics," I mean everything that you get from your normal starter kit (HDMI cord, power supply, etc.) Note that I'm running on a Raspberry Pi 4B with 8Gb RAM, and Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit (up to date as of the posting of this question).

Comment: Why do you want an Access Point if you already have access to a network?

Comment: You don't need to have an ethernet cable for seting up a hotspot. Without it, you obviously don't have access to the internet, but you could still access services that run on the RPI (e.g. you could SSH into it from your laptop)